# PHP Xdebug "Launch currently open script" works but "Listen for XDebug" doesn't

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, breakpoints

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, PHP 8.1, Xdebug 3, nginx & VSCode to debug local scripts and web things on localhost.

I've set up `launch.json` to run the scripts and web pages with Xdebug.
I can break on breakpoints when I 'Launch current script' but when I run 'Listen for Xdebug' the breakpoints are not hit.

```
echo 'PHP version: ' . PHP_VERSION:
   PHP version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9
echo 'Loaded PHP configuration file: ' . php_ini_loaded_file():
   Loaded PHP configuration file: /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
get_loaded_extensions():
    returns an array that contains 'xdebug'
xdebug_info():
   Step Debugger    ✘ disabled
```

This is the current `xdebug.ini` in mods-available:

```ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.log=/mnt/ramdisk/xdebug.log
```

EDIT:

I've also tried this:

Installed the Chrome extension to create a cookie for Xdebug. Enabled it for that page. No change... I'm using the Brave browser. That cookie is `XDEBUG_SESSION` and the value is `XDEBUG_ECLIPSE`.

Does anyone know why the 'Listen for Xdebug' doesn't work?

launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    // "log": true,
    "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php"
},
{
    "name": "Launch currently open script",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "port": 9003,
    "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/php"
},
```

output of xdebug_info() from command line:

```
\ \ / /  | |    | |                
 \ V / __| | ___| |__  _   _  __ _ 
  > < / _` |/ _ \ '_ \| | | |/ _` |
 / . \ (_| |  __/ |_) | |_| | (_| |
/_/ \_\__,_|\___|_.__/ \__,_|\__, |
                              __/ |
                             |___/ 

Version => 3.1.2
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

             Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)             
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Helpers => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

                            Optional Features                            
Compressed File Support => no
Clock Source => clock_gettime

                              Diagnostic Log                              
[Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

                              Step Debugging                              
Debugger is not active

                                   PHP                                   
                           Build Configuration                           
Version (Run Time) => 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9
Version (Compile Time) => 8.1.1
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
                                 Settings                                 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini


Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.mode => debug => debug
xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.use_compression => 0 => 0
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.log => /mnt/ramdisk/xdebug.log => /mnt/ramdisk/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
```

### output of xdebug_info from web page:

```
Version 3.1.2
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Helpers ✘ disabled  
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled   
Tracing ✘ disabled  
Optional Features
Compressed File Support no
Clock Source    clock_gettime
Diagnostic Log
Message Docs
  [Log Files] File '/mnt/ramdisk/xdebug.log' could not be opened. 
⚠️  [Step Debug] Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29). 
  [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(   
Step Debugging  Docs
Debugger    Not Active  
PHP
Build Configuration
Version (Run Time)  8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9
Version (Compile Time)  8.1.1
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Settings
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-inotify.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
Directive   Local Value Master Value    Docs
xdebug.mode debug   debug   
xdebug.start_with_request   trigger trigger 
xdebug.start_upon_error default default 
xdebug.output_dir   /tmp    /tmp    
xdebug.use_compression  0   0   
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value    
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value    
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value    
xdebug.log  /mnt/ramdisk/xdebug.log /mnt/ramdisk/xdebug.log 
xdebug.log_level    7   7   
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128 
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512 
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3   
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256 
xdebug.cli_color    0   0   
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off 
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0   
xdebug.halt_level   0   0   
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1  
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value    
xdebug.dump_globals On  On  
xdebug.dump_once    On  On  
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p   
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off 
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value    
xdebug.client_host  localhost   localhost   
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003    
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off 
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value    
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value    
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200 
xdebug.scream   Off Off 
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p  
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c    
xdebug.trace_format 0   0   
xdebug.trace_options    0   0   
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off 
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
```

Comment: Check your `php.ini` in the `[XDEBUG] section for `xdebug.mode =develop, debug` It need to have `debug` set, by default I dont think it does

Comment: /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini now contains[XDEBUG]
xdebug.mode=debug

It also has 'extension=xdebug' under [PHP]. I restarted nginx and get the same results. BTW I also tried changing the permissions of xdebug.so in /usr/lib/php/20210902, but that didn't help.

Comment: Check that the PHP is using the `php.ini` file you checked

Comment: running php_ini_loaded_file() in the web page returns /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini. This is the file that I checked.

Comment: I say 1) remove (comment out) `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger` and let it use the default "auto" value. 2) Check (and provide here) output of `xdebug_info()` captured via the same way where it does not work (web page or CLI). 3) Would be good to see VSCode config as well -- maybe you have made something wrong there (a typo or whatever) -- another pair of eyes may spot it.

Comment: I commented out that line in xdebug.ini. No difference. I'll post the output of xdebug_info() and what I have for launch.json above.

Comment: @user292344 1) Just in case -- it's very common on Linux nowadays to have one php.ini for CLI and another for a web server. In your question you are mentioning the web page and Chrome extension .. but the output is from CLI (where it works already). or do you mean that it also does NOT work in CLI when "Listen for Xdebug" config is used?

Comment: @user292344 Accordingly to your `xdebug_info()` output Xdebug tried to connect to `localhost:9003` but had no response. Looks like VSCode was not listening at that specific point or was already busy with another connection etc. Where the "try to debug" part comes from? Why it tries to connect? -- in normal circumstances it should not, unless it clearly sees the "debug me" flag (a COOKIE, GET/POST param or Xdebug ENV variable).

Comment: I'm not really using VSCode myself (another PHP IDE user), but when I've tried Xdebug in VSCode the following almost default config for "Listen for Xdebug" worked just fine for me: `{ "name": "Listen for Xdebug", "type": "php", "request": "launch", "port": 9003 },`. I then was controlling the "debug me" flag via Xdebug browser extension for my web page requests. For CLI I was using `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` or passing that param directly to PHP executable (using `-d` option) -- I did not want to play with ENV for "Listen" config.

Comment: Sorry about sending the cli version of xdebug_info(). I just added the web page version. I AM using the cookie generator extension on this page. In /etc/php/8.1 there are php.ini files in fpm and cli. I had read that you only need to edit ./mods-available/xdebug.ini. I did try some things in ./fpm/php.ini but couldn't get breakpoints to work in php in the web page that I am testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250841/discussion-between-user292344-and-lazyone).